# Autoexpand textbox while typing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am needing an autoexpanding textbox like facebook has for it's status updates.  I have code for it but for some reason it's not fully working correctly.  It's updating the textbox and expanding it, but it is doing it way too soon.  i am wanting it to expand when it gets to the end of the line.  But it is doing it after 20 characters are entered!  I have two different methods i have tried, they both do the same thing.  Any suggestions on changing my code?

```
  function sz(t) {
    var therows = 0
    var thetext = document.getElementById(t.id).value;
    var newtext = thetext.split("\n");
    therows += newtext.length

    document.getElementById(t.id).rows = therows;
    return false;
  }



    function sz(t) 
{
    a = t.value.split('\n');
    b = 1;

    for (x = 0; x < a.length; x++) 
    {
        if (a[x].length >= t.cols) 
        {
            b += Math.floor(a[x].length / t.cols);
        }
    }

    b += a.length;

    if (b > t.rows) 
    {
        t.rows = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5J7ND/4/)

I think your problem was using `txtbox.id` rather than just passing the id.

Comment: I can't get it to only pass the id.  And i don't think that will make a difference, because it seems to be getting the id and the txtbox properly

Comment: Did you even visit the link in my answer?

Comment: Yes i did nick, your link is passing in the textbox and is running of the keypress for enter instead of going to the next line.

Comment: The problem is that pressing the enter key creates your `\n` if you just type in the box and let it wrap, it's simply wrapping. I'm not sure how or if it's possible to detect accurately.